# Private Params Method not showing form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

So I am working on creating a playercard, which is basically a profile page for a user. The issue I am having on the backend is my private method playercard_params is only returning user_id, and not all the information inputted into the form...although regular params shows all the data needed to create the playercard. I thought the issue might be on the frontend, but working my way backwards came to the conclusion the issue is here on the backend.

Here is my controller:

```
class Api::V1::PlayercardController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user 

    def index      
        if params[:user_id]
            @playercard = @user.playercard
        else
            @playercard = Playercard.all   
        end
        render json: @playercard
    end

    def show
        @playercard = Playercard.find(params[:id])
        render json: @playercard
    end

    def create

            @playercard = Playercard.new(playercard_params)
            binding.pry 
            if @playercard.save
                render json: @user
            else
                render json: {
                error: @playercard.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
                }
            end
    end

    def update
        @playercard = Playercard.find(params[:id])
            if @playercard.update(playercard_params)
                render json: @playercard
            else
                render json: {
                error: @playercard.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
                }
            end
    end

    private 

    def playercard_params
      params.require(:playercard).permit(:player_nickname, :player_height_in_feet, :player_height_in_inches, :player_weight, :player_age, :player_fav_player, :user_id)
    end

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

end
```

My playercard model:

```
class Playercard < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user 

    validates :player_nickname, :player_height_in_feet, :player_height_in_inches, :player_weight, :player_age, :player_fav_player, presence: true
end
```

and the serializer if that helps:

```
class PlayercardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :player_nickname, :player_height_in_feet, :player_height_in_inches, :player_weight, :player_age, :player_fav_player

    belongs_to :user
  end
```

Here are my params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"playerNickname"=>"white mamba", "playerHeightFeet"=>"6", "playerHeightInches"=>"3", "playerAge"=>"30", "playerWeight"=>"170", "playerFavPlayer"=>"Kobe", "user_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"api/v1/playercard", "action"=>"create", "playercard"=><ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>1} permitted: false>} permitted: false>
```

When I submit the form on the front end, I get errors saying each field is empty...in the pry, if I type playercard_params, only user_id shows up (with the correct id)

Comment: Can you please add your params (as submitted to the server) to your question? Otherwise, we are left guessing.

Comment: That second one with just user_id is what playercard_params returns

Comment: The problem is obvious. The `params` you are trying to `permit` are not contained in the `playercard` hash. BTW, you should put additional code in your original question (by using the `edit` button below the tags) instead of pasting into a comment.

Comment: @jvillian Yes of course, thanks for reminding me. So is the issue with my playercard_params method, not sure how to fix this?

Comment: I guess an issue I might see as an issue is the naming convention?? on the rails side i use snake_case for the attributes and on the react side camelCase is the convention, so I see now my params are in camelCase...could that be an issue??

Comment: The params you are trying to `.permit` are not inside the hash that you `.require`. Either modify your form so that the params you want to `permit` are inside the `playercard` hash, or reformulate your `.require().permit()`. And, yeah, your variable names are whack - multiple problems there. `playerHeightFeet`, for e.g., has no relationship whatsoever to `player_height_in_feet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by lining up the naming convention for the attributes with the front-end and back-end. And it worked!

Thank you @jvillian for the insight!!